# c++ boost time validation when parsing a wrong input

Tags: c++, validation, boost

I'm learning `C++` and making a simple application, and I have the following code that parses a `std::string` to a `ptime`:

```
ptimePointer CsvHelper::string_to_ptime(const std::string& s, const int mode, 
    timePointer pt)
{
    const std::locale formats[] = {
        std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%d/%m/%Y H:%M:%S")),
        std::locale(std::locale::classic(),new boost::posix_time::time_input_facet("%H:%M"))
    };

    std::istringstream is(s);
    is.imbue(formats[mode]);
    is >> *pt;
}

return pt;
```

The problem is that if I pass a letter `"a"`, it will be created a `ptime` with a special value "not-a-date-time".

Ok, so I check the docs and learned the if I create a `ptime` with the default constructor I get a `ptime` with the same kind. So, in my code I validated the input with the following code:

```
boost::posix_time::ptime ptime;
if (*this->myDate != ptime)
{
    ...
} else 
{
    treat the problem;
}
```

I feel that this is not a clear solution, what is a better way to validate this date?

Comment: Judging from the name of the function, you are reading a ISO8601 date in from a `.csv` file. Would [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) be helpful at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ptime has a is_not_a_date_time() function.
so you could do

```
if(myDate.is_not_a_date_time())
   do_something();
```